# SQL: selection of specific value outputs

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to mySQL but really desperate. Please try to take it easy on me.

I want to create a report about a hotel. Right now, my query can show me, how many different journeys where booked with how many nights.

To give an example:

```
SELECT i.numberofnights,
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.nod >='1' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) as journeyCount
    FROM itinerary i
    WHERE i.arrival BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
    GROUP BY i.numberofnights
```

My Output:

```
NoN   |   journeyCount
1     |   18
2     |   6
3     |   4
4     |   13
5     |   12
6     |   5
7     |   9
```

It shows that I have 18 journeys with 1 night, 6 with 2 nights and so on. My wish is to make a selection, so combine alle the results for 1 to 3 nights and 4 to 7 nights.
Please help me!

My desired Output:

```
NoN   |  journeyCount
1-3   |  28
4-7   |  39
```

Thank you in advance!! :)

Comment: Are the ranges fixed or they vary based on user's input?

Comment: They are fixed but in the end I will need five different ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *integer division* in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT (i.numberofnights-1) DIV 3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN i.nod >=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as journeyCount
FROM itinerary i
WHERE i.arrival BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
GROUP BY (i.numberofnights-1) DIV 3
```

If you want *just two* segments, one for `<=3` and another one for `> 3`, then you can use:

```
SELECT IF(CASE WHEN i.numberofnights <= 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END = 0, '1-3', '4-7') AS NoN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN i.nod >=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as journeyCount
FROM itinerary i
WHERE i.arrival BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
GROUP BY CASE WHEN i.numberofnights <= 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

**Edit:**

To get bucket tags like '1-3', '4-6', etc you can use the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(((i.numberofnights-1) DIV 3 + 1) * 3 - 2, 
              '-', 
              ((i.numberofnights-1) DIV 3 + 1) * 3) AS NoN, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN i.nod >=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as journeyCount
FROM itinerary i
WHERE i.arrival BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
GROUP BY (i.numberofnights-1) DIV 3
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1079/7)

Comment: The first solution works great, thank you so much!!! Is there a way to rename the values from the first column, so I would get a result that displays the different intervals? Like 1-3, 4-6 and so on?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask so much of you but could you probably take a look at my other problem please? The question's name is: "Selection of specific outputs with a string column"